# мониторинг трафика Wi-Fi по логину

Tags: сеть, wifi, freeradius

В сети находится несколько WiFi роутеров, требуется по логину/паролю пользователя отслеживать посещенные web-сайты.
Планируется использование RADIUS сервера на Linux для авторизации пользователя в сети(freeradius+daloradius). Каким образом сопоставить с пользователем посещенные веб страницы? Что потребуется помимо RADIUS для реализации? Устанавливать снифферы трафика на каждом устройстве - не решение.

Answer (score 0):

- Из радиуса будете знать соответствие логину IP адрес.
- Будете знать IP адрес - сможете посчитать прохождение трафика через интерефейс
- чтоб узнать какие сайты посещал пользователь - лучше поставть прозрачный прокси, например squid. А в принципе и трафик тут-же можно учитывать какимнибудь парсером логов